# preg_replace limit whitespace chars

Tags: php

```
<?php $keys_array = explode(',', $row['meta_keys']);
    foreach($keys_array as $keys_array){
        echo '<a href="foo/bar'. $keys_array .'">'. $keys_array .'</a>';
    }

?>
```

I know to use `preg_replace`

But I'm still a newbie. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: What's the question or specific difficulty? Explain input and expected output.

Comment: @mario I'm simple trying to limit the whitespace for this string. But Don't know where to put preg-replace at along with the () to replace the white space.

Comment: **WHERE** is the whitespace? Limit it how? Strip it? Compact it?

Comment: Research `trim()` or `str_replace()`, or possibly just `str_getcsv()` instead of explode.